# PayPal error when initializing

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I use paypal Mobile Payment Libraries for ios **(iPhone 5.01 iOS)**
I cannot initialize PayPal in my application.

After

```
[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];
```

I receive error:

```
2012-02-11 12:01:11.623 myapp[7281:707] Checking Error********************
2012-02-11 12:01:11.625 myapp[7281:707] Posting Error: 2147483647
```

And show alert with message: in title - Error, and Body Message : 500000

It occurs when is set any variables like CFBundleDisplayName in InfoPlist.strings (CFBundleDisplayName1 = "MyApp"; or CFBundleDisplayName = "MyApp"). When i remove this from InfoPlist.strings  all work fine!

What is this mean?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like PayPal is banning bundle ids which have translated app names.

I have had different CFBundleDisplayName in my Info.plist than in the translation files. This way the PayPal module did exactly the same as you. After running the app one time with this configuration I was not able to run the same bundle id in my test project (containing only the PayPal lib's example code) either anymore.

After I removed the translation and set the bundle id to a new one, the PayPal button started to work again.

I think this is a very serious issue at PayPal (for example some could ban bundle id's of ohers apps, even with live apps in the App Store!). I will contact them soon about this issue.

Comment: What is this translation and How can i remove it? Please let me know? I am getting same Error 500000

Comment: I am a Titanium developer, and all what I wrote is about Titanium. For native development, I assume you have to fix this with a new app name in the Info.plist directly.

Comment: @JaakL hi i am able to run there demo example. but when i change bundle identifier and run log in button is not enable in paypal window http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040297/paypal-mpl-login-button-disabled-on-device

Comment: I'm writing a Swift App in XCode 6.1. There was no "Bundle display name" defined in Info.plist. I had to add it manually and set to the same value as in the demo app - ${PRODUCT_NAME}. After that the button worked fine.