# PayPal Integration in Ipad

Tags: ipad, ios4, paypal-sandbox, ios-universal-app

I am creating an ipad and iphone (Universal App).

I have implemented Paypal in iPhone but when I am going to implement in iphone there I am facing an issue . There is an error showing:

Checking Error********************

Posting Error: 2147483647

Please look into this if anybody can help.

Thanks,

Cp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to check that : [Paypal Error Initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238266/paypal-error-when-initializing)

I think it could resolve your problem (translation and bundle id change).

Comment: Ya, I have already tried this. One more thing it is working on iphone but issue in ipad.