# Paypal MPL login button disabled on device

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal

I have gone through several questions with similar problem but could not find any solution for it. I have followed steps given working in sandbox mode.. after following code i get paypal window.

```
[[PayPal getPayPalInst] checkoutWithPayment:payment];
```

In paypal window i can login using email and password. which works on simulator but on device log in button remains disabled after giving valid credentials.

[image]

Thanks in advance

i am able to run there demo example. but when i change bundle identifier and check then log in button is not enable in paypal window

Now i found out that its disabled for my particular bundle identifier as when i use different profile with its bundle identifier its working.

Do we have to register our bundle identifier? or any particular reason for it.

**I am using Paypal MPL version 2.1.0.**

Comment: did you get your own appId from apps.paypal.com ?

Comment: @Praveen no,i have my app live on app store. I am using developer profile bundle identifier but when i change and use some different profile its working..

Comment: @Praveen I am using sandbox mode Paypal MPL

Answer (score 0):

please double check the seller account "sunny.g-faciliator@intelgain.com" (receiverEmail) - I guess it should be "sunny.g-facilitator@intelgain.com" (a "t" is missing in "facilitator") and this might cause the issue.

Comment: yes, you are right about that mistake but that is not problem. log in button remains disabled.    and also mine is working sometime i.e log in button is enabled but most of time it is disabled

Comment: Hi, I run a quick test with the latest version of SDK for iOS and the Login button works fine.   I'd probably focus my concern on the email address used, can you try the login with an email address that does not contain dots? (e.g. sanket@intelgain.com)

Comment: I am using MPL not SDK and i have used email Id without "."(e.g jagan@intelgain.com). but problem exists.

Comment: @PayPal_Federica We are facing the same problem. I don't think its the email address. The same app works fine when run on Simulator, but the Pay button is disabled on the device running iOS 7.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)ChainPayment
{
[PayPal getPayPalInst].shippingEnabled = TRUE;

//optional, set dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled to TRUE if you want to compute
//shipping and tax based on the user's address choice, default: FALSE
[PayPal getPayPalInst].dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled = FALSE;

//optional, choose who pays the fee, default: FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER
[PayPal getPayPalInst].feePayer = FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER;

//for a payment with multiple recipients, use a PayPalAdvancedPayment object
PayPalAdvancedPayment *payment = [[PayPalAdvancedPayment alloc] init] ;
payment.paymentCurrency = @"USD";

//receiverPaymentDetails is a list of PPReceiverPaymentDetails objects
payment.receiverPaymentDetails = [NSMutableArray array];

//NSArray *nameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Frank's", @"Robert's", @"Julie's",nil];

for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
    PayPalReceiverPaymentDetails *details = [[PayPalReceiverPaymentDetails alloc] init];

    details.description = @"Bear Components";
    if(i==1)
    {
        details.recipient =[[[_emailDictionary valueForKey:@"secondary"] valueForKey:@"1"] valueForKey:@"email"];//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"example-merchant-%d@paypal.com", 4 - i];
    }
    if(i==2)
    {
        details.recipient =[[_emailDictionary valueForKey:@"primary"] valueForKey:@"email"];// [NSString stringWithFormat:@"example-merchant-%d@paypal.com", 4 - i];

    }
    details.merchantName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"merchant  name"];

    /*unsigned long long order, tax, shipping;
     order = i * 100;
     tax = 0.0;
     shipping =0.0;
     primary =     {
     email = "m,b@rew.com";
     "first_name" = aj;
     "last_name" = Shar;
     plan = Free;
     "profit_percent" = 68;
     "reffer_from" = "<null>";
     };
     secondary =     {
     1 =         {
     email = "pushnd@gmail.com";
     "profit_percent" = 32;
     };
     };
     }

     //subtotal of all items for this recipient, without tax and shipping
     details.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:order exponent:-2 isNegative:FALSE];

     //invoiceData is a PayPalInvoiceData object which contains tax, shipping, and a list of PayPalInvoiceItem objects
     details.invoiceData = [[PayPalInvoiceData alloc] init];
     details.invoiceData.totalShipping = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:shipping exponent:-2 isNegative:FALSE];
     details.invoiceData.totalTax = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:tax exponent:-2 isNegative:FALSE];

     //invoiceItems is a list of PayPalInvoiceItem objects
     //NOTE: sum of totalPrice for all items must equal details.subTotal
     //NOTE: example only shows a single item, but you can have more than one
     details.invoiceData.invoiceItems = [NSMutableArray array];
     PayPalInvoiceItem *item = [[PayPalInvoiceItem alloc] init];
     NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:_price];

     details.subTotal=number;
     item.totalPrice = details.subTotal;
     item.name = @"Audio";
     [details.invoiceData.invoiceItems addObject:item];*/

    //the only difference between setting up a chained payment and setting
    //up a parallel payment is that the chained payment must have a single
    //primary receiver.  the subTotal + totalTax + totalShipping of the
    //primary receiver must be greater than or equal to the sum of
    //payments being made to all other receivers, because the payment is
    //being made to the primary receiver, then the secondary receivers are
    //paid by the primary receiver.
    if (i == 2)
    {
        details.isPrimary = TRUE;
        details.merchantName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mercahnt name or app name"];
        NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:_price];
        details.subTotal=number;

    }
    else
    {

        float secondaryPrice=[_price floatValue];
        secondaryPrice=(secondaryPrice*[[[[_emailDictionary valueForKey:@"secondary"] valueForKey:@"1"] valueForKey:@"profit_percent"] integerValue])/100;
        NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [fmt setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
        NSString *stringPrice=[fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:secondaryPrice]];
        NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:stringPrice];
        details.subTotal=number;
    }

    [payment.receiverPaymentDetails addObject:details];
}
[[PayPal getPayPalInst] advancedCheckoutWithPayment:payment];
   }
```